# How to fix jumps in time data

Tags: matlab, timestamp

I have some Time(s) vs Load(kN) data where the time record undergoes a negative jump of 86400 seconds at regular intervals throughout the record. I need a mat lab code that can detect these jumps in order to change the data from something like this:

```
(1 , 21) 

(2 , 22)

(3 , 23) 

(-86397 , 24)

(-86398 , 25)

(-86399 , 26)
```

into something like this:

```
(1 , 21)

(2 , 22)

(3 , 23)

(4 , 24)

(5 , 25)

(6 , 26)
```

Comment: With the info you give us I would.. `data(1,:)=1:size(data,1)`

Comment: With those values, shouldn't the resulting first column be 1 2 3 3 2 1?

Comment: yep, or `ix2offset=data(1,:)<0;data(1,ix2offset)=data(1,ix2offset)+86400`

Answer (score 1):

I assume you mean

```
data = [1 , 21
        2 , 22
        3 , 23
   -86396 , 24
   -86395 , 25
   -86394 , 26]
```

that is, there is a negative jump and then the sequence keeps on increasing. This would give you the output you show.

If that's the case, what you want is similar to phase unwrapping, only that the range of values is different. So you could use [`unwrap`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/unwrap.html) with the appropriate scale correction:

```
scale = 2*pi/86400;
data(:,1) = unwrap(data(:,1)*scale)/scale;
```

Or you could do the unwrapping yourself:

```
N = 86400;
d = mod(diff(data(:,1))-N/2,N)-N/2; %// differences with large jumps corrected
data(2:end,1) = data(1,1) + cumsum(d);
```